# With clause changes keypath

Tags: ractivejs

I have the following template:

```
{{#each Posts}}
{{#with { Post: this } }}
  <h2 on-click="doSomething">{{Title}}</h2>
  ...
{{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

When I click on the header and doSomething get called, I get `"${{Post:Posts-0}}"` in event keypath. But I need to get access to the post keypath: "Posts.0" to modify some of its properties. What is the right way to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you using the with block?

Comment: I need to be able to call "Post.Id" down in the hierarchy instead of "../../../Id"

Comment: Huh? Could you please eloborate that final comment?

Comment: @Leakim, I'm talking about ancestor references (from here: http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/references). When I render post comments I wanna be able to postId by calling Post.Id instead of ../Id

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3v69zhm7/2/) something along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Leakim, I've updated your sample to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3v69zhm7/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `{{#with { a: b } }}` block for aliasing in Ractive has some limitations, as it's not true aliasing, it's simply creating an expression with an object literal. It's a needed enhancement to offer true aliasing with something like `{{#each Post in Posts}}` or `{{#each Posts as Post}}`.

As far as what you can do today, you can add the keypath to the `with` block:

```
{{#with { Post: this, keypath: @keypath } }}
```

And then either pass in:

```
  <h2 on-click="doSomething:{{keypath}}">{{Title}}</h2>
```

Or access in the event via `this.event.context.keypath`. See http://jsfiddle.net/w0npbnrz/ for both of these in action.

You also could use `{{#each Posts:p}}` in which case you could get the keypath via `'Posts.' + this.event.index.p`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Are there any plans to implement "light aliasing" (that will not change keypath) in Ractive.js?